# xslt namespace identification in out put

Tags: xslt

I'm using the following xslt sheet. This transformation is working great except when it returns , it is adding unnecessary namespace declarations for each element. I only the namespace declared in the root element. Please see the OUTPUT below.

I'm not sure what's going on. Please help.

XSLT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0" xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:apply-templates/>

</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/ | @* | node()">
         <xsl:copy>
             <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>

         </xsl:copy>
         </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tei:item">
        <xsl:variable name="item" select="."></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="\(([^\)]*)\)">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <item xml:id="aa-meta-{regex-group(1)}"><xsl:value-of select="$item"/></item>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>


    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Sample OUTPUT:

```
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude">
<teiHeader>
<fileDesc>
<titleStmt>
<title>Auctoritates Aristotelis</title>
<editor xml:id="JH">Hamesse</editor>
</titleStmt>
<publicationStmt>
<p/>  
</publicationStmt>
<sourceDesc>
<p>Auctoritates Aristotelis, pp. ??-??</p>
</sourceDesc>
</fileDesc>
</teiHeader>
<text xml:lang="la">
<body>
<list>
<head>Sequuntur nunc auctoritates Philosophi, id est amatoris sapientiae.
Et primo primi libri Metaphysicae.</head>
<item xmlns="" xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="aa-meta-1">(1) Omnes homines naturaliter scire desiderant.</item>
<item xmlns="" xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="aa-meta-2">(2) Sensus visus multas nobis rerum differentias demonstrat.</item>
<item xmlns="" xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="aa-meta-3">(3) Solum hominum genus arte et ratione vivit.</item>
<item xmlns="" xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="aa-meta-4">(4) Experientia facit artem; inexperientia vero casum.</item>
<item xmlns="" xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="aa-meta-5">(5) Actus et operationes sunt circa singularia, quia medicus non sanat
hominem in communi, sed Socratem vel aliquem alium in parti-
culari, similiter et in aliis.</item>
```

Comment: What does the source look like? Can you post it here (or the nodes and namespaces involved)?

Answer (score 0):

Your stylesheet says it's adding a non-namespaced `<item>` element. Since the parent (`<list>`) inherits the default namespace set on the `<TEI>` element, that means the `<item>` has to cancel the default, which it does by saying `xmlns=""`. This is correct operation.

If you want the `<item>` to be in the TEI namespace, the stylesheet has to say so ... for example, by saying

```
     <item xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="aa-meta-{regex-group(1)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="$item"/>
     </item>
```